# Javascript loop with binded click event always returning last result

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a for loop running in javascript. In this loop I am creating a list item and binding a click event to it. When I click this list item I want it to call a function with the data from the current loop object as a parameter.

The problem is, no matter what list item I click. The data that is being passed as the parameter is the last element of the object I am looping rather than the current one that is being clicked.

```
for(e in data) {

    var suggestItem = $('<li>'+ data[e]['name'] +'</li>');

    suggestItem.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('activeSuggestion');
        suggestSelect(suggestField, data[e]);      
    });

    suggestList.append(suggestItem);

}
```

I think I understand why this happens but not sure how I should handle it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Event Handler created in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774636/jquery-event-handler-created-in-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break the closure over `e`.

Since you're using jQuery, the easiest way would be to save the current value of `e` with jQuery's `data` function.  Since all function parameters in JavaScript are passed by value, this effectively breaks the closure; now your click handler will work with what the value of `e` is when the handler was created, and not the value `e` holds when the loop ends.

```
for(e in data) {

    var suggestItem = $('<li>'+ data[e]['name'] +'</li>');

    suggestItem.data('savedE', e).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('activeSuggestion');
        suggestSelect(suggestField, data[$(this).data('savedE')]);
    });

    suggestList.append(suggestItem);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic Javascript closure question. When the click event is triggered (when you click on something), the loop has already finished executing. The value of `e` is whatever the last key in `data` is. The solution to the problem is to create a new scope inside of your loop.

```
for(var e in data) {
    (function(datum) {
        suggestList.append(
            $('<li>' + datum.name + '</li>')
            .click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('activeSuggestion');
                suggestSelect(suggestField, datum);      
            });
        );
    })(data[e]);
}
```

Javascript is function scoped, so whenever a new function is encountered, a new scope is created. The above code "traps" the value of `data[e]` into `datum` because it passes it as a parameter to the function. Another way to code it which may be less confusing:

```
for(var e in data) {
    (function() {
        var datum = data[e];
        suggestList.append(
            $('<li>' + datum.name + '</li>')
            .click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('activeSuggestion');
                suggestSelect(suggestField, datum);      
            });
        );
    })();
}
```

It doesn't pass in a parameter to the function, but because Javascript is function scoped, every time the click event is triggered it will look for where `datum` was assigned.

Also please note the `for(VAR e in data)` which will stop `e` from becoming a global variable.