# Creating closures within a for loop - am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am prob. being pretty dense here but I can't figure out exactly what is going on in the code below.

What I am trying to do is attach two, separate, handlers to the change event of a field. Each handler is set up by looping over an array and using the items in the array to effect the output of the handler when it runs - hopefully will become clear when you look at the example code.

Code follows:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        //
        // Create some test input fields on the page...
        //
        $('<br />').insertAfter($('body > *:last'));
        $('<input type="text" name="t0" id="t0" value="" />').insertAfter($('body > *:last'));
        $('<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value="" />').insertAfter($('body > *:last'));

        //
        // The problematic part  - for me at least...
        //
        var arr = new Array(1, 2);
        for (var a in arr) {
            // Using Chrome console here for logging
            console.log("## " + a);
            $('#t0').change(function () {
                console.log(">> " + a)
            });
        }
    });
```

So what I would expect to happen when I add a value to the first field is, from within the console (running these examples within Chrome):

```
## 0
## 1
>> 1
>> 2
```

What I get is:

```
## 0
## 1
>> 1
>> 1
```

I would have expected the function passed to the handler would form a closure over the value of `a` and I would end up with two functions being bound to the handler, one in which `a` had the value `1` and one in which `a` had the value `2`.

Ideas?

Cheers - kris

Comment: Quick note: your not closing your document ready function. Add a closing bracket `)`

Comment: Understanding JavaScript function scope would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774636/jquery-event-handler-created-in-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two big mistakes here:

First of all, the `for (a in x)` doesn't work like you expect it to: it iterates over  object properties, not over array elements.

The other mistake is that `a` changes by the time the function gets called. A good way to achieve the desired functionality is like this:

```
for(var a=0; a<arr.length; a++) {
    (function(a) {
        // now you can use "a"
    })(arr[a]);
}
```

To see what happens with the `for` loop if you don't create a closure, see this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var functions = [];

for(var a=0; a<arr.length; a++) {
    functions.push(function() {
        console.log(a);
    })
}

// now execute all the functions
for(var i=0; i<functions.length; i++) {
    functions[i]();
}
```

Now all the functions will log  `3`, which is the index of the last element in the array + 1 (`arr[0] == 1, arr[1] == 2, arr[2] == 3`). What happens is that the `for` loop creates those functions at each iteration, but they get executed *after* the loop finishes, when `a == arr.length`.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response! Good explanation of the mistakes I have made. Makes sense now - so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the "for" loop, try jQuery's [own tool](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
 $(arr).each(function(a) {
       console.log("## " + a);
        $('#t0').change(function () {
            console.log(">> " + a)
        });
  });
```

This works as intended.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that closures use the most recent values of their variables. That is, if you create a closure with `a` equal to 1 and then create another one when `a` equals to 2, both closures will use the last value, 2. This is admittedly confusing, but this is how it works.

Comment: thanks for the response - also helps with my understanding, so thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like this:

```js
for (var a in arr) {
    (function (a) {
        // thanks to closure variable a is local here
        $('#t0').change(function () {
            console.log(">> " + a);
        });
    }(a)); 
}
```

or like this:

```
for (var a in arr) {
    $('#t0').change((function (a) {
        return function () {
            // returned function has access to local variable a from 
            // outer function
            console.log(">> " + a);
        };
    }(a));
}
```

Trick is to put variable a in deeper scope than for loop.
To be easier to read two above snippets could be written as:

```
for (var a in arr) {
    (function (inner_a) {
        // thanks to closure variable a is local here
        $('#t0').change(function () {
            console.log(">> " + inner_a);
        });
    }(a)); 
}

for (var a in arr) {
    $('#t0').change((function (inner_a) {
        return function () {
            // returned function has access to local variable a from 
            // outer function
            console.log(">> " + inner_a);
        };
    }(a));
}
```

BTW. it would be better to use classic for (var i...) instead of for .. in loop unless you are interating through object properties. And $('#t0') should be cached:

```js
var cachedEl = $('#t0');

for (var a=0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    (function (inner_a) {
        // thanks to closure variable a is local here
        cachedEl.change(function () {
            console.log(">> " + inner_a);
        });
    }(a)); 
}
// or
for (var a=0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    cachedEl.change((function (inner_a) {
        return function () {
            // returned function has access to local variable a from 
            // outer function
            console.log(">> " + inner_a);
        };
    }(a));
}
```