# Different hover functions get shared callback functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a program with bubbles of text. When you hover the text it is supposed to show another text instead. Each bubble have unique text strings stored in Json format. **The problem is that they all get the same callback for the hover effect.** Every bubbles text is set to the same as the last bubble in the datastructure.

Code:

```
     function createBubbles() {
            for ( var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
              var bubbleInfo = bubbles[i];
              var text1=bubbleInfo['small_text'];
              var text2=bubbleInfo['full_text'];
              $('body').append(BubbleTemplate).children('#newBubble').attr("id",
                  'bubble' + i).hide().html('<a>'+text1+'</a>').hover(function(){
                    console.log("hover"+i);
                    $(this).children('a').css({'font-size': '14px'}).text(text2);
                  }, function(){
                    $(this).children('a').css({'font-size': '40px'}).text(text1);
                  });
            }
          }
```

Datastructure:

```
 var bubbles = [
          {
            "start": "0.05",
            "stop": "0.4",
            "small_text": "Head1",
            "full_text": "description1"
          },
          {
            "start": "0.3",
            "stop": "0.7",
            "small_text": "Head2",
            "full_text": "description2"
          },
          {
            "start": "0.35",
            "stop": "0.8",
            "small_text": "Head3",
            "full_text": "description3"
          }, ];
```

Html template:

```
<div id="newBubble" class="text-bubble animated"><a></a></div>
```

"Console.log("hover"+i)" always prints: hover3 even if I hover bubble 1

Comment: and [jQuery Event Handler created in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7774636/218196)

Comment: and [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6487366/218196)

Comment: it is possible, I will check it out. Thanks